# NoSuchElementException in Selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-mining

**Hello Experts!** I am new to programming I am facing a problem in finding specific element.
Here is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.ackerwines.com/auctions/?auctionId=1328')
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='checkbox']").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@id='sm-agree-button-wrap'])[3]").click()
time.sleep(5)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='elementor-shortcode'])[6]").click()
except:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[@class='elementor-icon'])[1]").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='xoo-el-username']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='xoo-el-username']").send_keys('malikibrahim6786@gmail.com')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='xoo-el-password']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='xoo-el-password']").send_keys('Malik786')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='xoo-el-rememberme']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@type='submit'])[2]").click()
time.sleep(15)

prod = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='auctionLotsList']")
print(prod)
```

**The error I get is**

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='auctionLotsList']"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

Comment: The obvious explanation is that the element isn't there.  What makes you think that it should be there?

Answer (score 1):

NoSuchElementException occurs when selenium can’t find the element. To resolve this, double check that the element xpath is correct. Another issue causing this is that website is still loading. You can add a 1 or 2 second delay with time.sleep(). Lastly, you can catch the exception with a try: and except: by putting all the find_by_xpath under it.